Knuth's derivation of a geometric progression by manipulating summations
In page 31 of The Art of Computer Programming (Vol. 1), Knuth derives a closed form equation for a geometric progression to demonstrate techniques for manipulating summations (which I'll partially repeat here):
He starts by expanding the sum $\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n}ax^j$. I am having trouble understanding step 4:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a + ax + ... + ax^n &= \sum_{0 \leq j \leq n} ax^j \\
                    &= a + \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n}ax^j && \text{(step 1) by manipulation of the domain} \\
                    &= a + x\sum_{1 \leq j \leq n}ax^{j-1} && \text{(step 2) by a special case of the distributive law} \\
                    &= a + x\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n-1}ax^j && \text{(step 3) by changing the index variable} \\
                    &= a + x\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n}ax^j - ax^{n+1} && \text{(step 4) by manipulating the domain} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
I don't understand why we subtract $ax^{n+1}$ rather than $ax^n$, which is what I expected. In step 4, we've extended the index range from $[0,n-1]$ to $[0,n]$, which means we've included an extra term $j=n$ in the summation. In order to account for this extra value, shouldn't we subtract $ax^n$?
This step is described as an application of the manipulating the domain rule, which I suspect I'm misunderstanding. Earlier in the text, this is defined as:
$$
\sum_{R(j)}a_j + \sum_{S(j)}a_j = \sum_{R(j) \text{ or } S(j)}a_j + \sum_{R(j) \text{ and } S(j)}a_j
$$
With the following example:
$$
\sum_{1 \leq j \leq m}a_j + \sum_{m \leq j \leq n} = \Big ( \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n}a_j \Big) + a_m
$$
Where the second summation is reduced to $a_m$ because $R(j) \wedge S(j)$ is only true when $j=m$.
I've read this explanation of Knuth's rule, which confirms that we can interpret it as "sum two ranges and account for the overlap". But that doesn't explain where the $n+1$ comes from.
How does this work?

I guess you are forgetting the $x$ outside the summation

Ah, that'd be it. This explains how it could be expanded into two summations and then reduced to a single term.

Starting from the last step
$$a+x\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n}ax^j-ax^{n+1}=a+x\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n-1}ax^j+xax^n-ax^{n+1}=a+x\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n-1}ax^j$$
